# Odoo 10 : Exit Qweb loop

Tags: xml, for-loop, odoo, qweb

I have a below code :

```
<t t-foreach="doc.order_lines_layouted()" t-as="page">
     <t t-foreach="page" t-as="layout_category">
         <t t-foreach="layout_category['lines']" t-as="l">
              <t t-if="l.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product'" > 

                  <br/><br/> <br/><br/>
                  <p>Bill To: </p>
                  <!-- Adds customers contact details on top right corner -->
                  <div t-field="doc.partner_invoice_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;contactname&quot;, &quot;name&quot;,  &quot;phone&quot;, &quot;email&quot;, &quot;fax&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: True, &quot;phone_icons&quot;: True, &quot;email_icons&quot;: True}"/>
                  <p>Customer VAT#:&#160; <span t-field= "doc.partner_invoice_id.vat"/> <br/>
                  Customer#:&#160;<span t-field= "doc.partner_id.id"/>
                                </p>

              </t>
         </t>
     </t>
</t>
```

I want to exit the loops once the t-if condition is satisfied. How can i do this? is there anything like **exit();** exists in qweb?

**Info:** I know below solution but this is not an elegant solution :

```
<t t-set="foo" t-value="False"/>

    <t t-foreach="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]" t-as="i">

        <t t-if="foo == False">

             <p><t t-esc="i"/></p>

             <t t-if="i==3">

                 <t t-set="foo" t-value="True"/>

             </t>

        </t>

    </t>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to have an option like a `<t t-break/>` for qweb but AFAIK there is nothing to allow you to do that. What you could do is prepare the dataset or collection to be iterated by filtering out all the non needed elements from the collection before entering the t-foreach loop

Comment: ok but i dont think this solution will work in my case where i want to simply print something if one of the product is 'product'. I will use that non elegant solution .Btw thanks for suggesting another approach .Might be useful in future!

Comment: The solution you mention does nothing to do with your question about: `I want to exit the loops once the t-if condition is satisfied. How can i do this? is there anything like exit(); exists in qweb?`